# Add centered text above span element

Tags: html, css

In my html app I just want to add some centered text above span element here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/19qwxkhf/9/

Here is html and css:

```
<article class="tab-pane" id="tab-reporting">
  <section>
      <ul class="active">
        <li>
          <label>Test 1</label>
          <span class="badge badge-success">Test1</span>
          This text should be above Hello badge and centered
          <span class="badge badge-important">Hello</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>Test 2</label>
          <span class="badge badge-success">Test1</span>
          This text should be above Hello 2 badge and centered
          <span class="badge badge-important">Hello 2</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </section>
</article>

/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}


.badge-success {
  background: green !important;
  color: #fff !important;

  min-width: 0px !important;

  /* If you need */
  padding: 0px !important;

}

.badge-important {
  background: red !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

#tab-reporting {
  padding-bottom: 100px;

  ul {
    list-style-type: none;

    &.inactive {
      margin-top: 25px;
      opacity: 0.3;
    }
  }

  label {
    width: 245px;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }

  li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: table;

    &.survey-start {
      margin-top: 15px;
    }

    > label {
      font-weight: normal;
      margin-left: 30px;
      padding-top: 7px;

      &.colspan {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }

    .colspan-nest {
      text-indent: 25px;
    }

    > span {
      display: table-cell;
      min-width: 175px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 0;
      background: #ddd;
      padding: 7px;

      &.no-background {
        background: none;
      }
    }
  }

  .txt {
    padding-left: 5px;
  }

  .lh {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    padding: 12px 0 5px;
  }
}
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
span {
  width: 100px;
}
```

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: `label {text-align:center;display:block}`

Comment: Label should not be centered. `This text should be above Hello badge and centered` should be centered.

Comment: Wrap that text in a div then `text-align:center`

Comment: Also doesn't work as expected. I've tried that solutions before I asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: Compile your preprocessed CSS and I'll give you a serious answer.

Comment: Everything is in jsfiddle...

Comment: Do you know the difference between CSS and preprocessed CSS like LESS, SCSS, SASS, etc?

Comment: can you give us a screenshot of what you want ?

Comment: I dont quiet get what you want? You want the text above the hello badge and centered. Is that not what i did? Or is the fiddle missing something? Cuse i see LESS but no less compiler has been included.

Comment: Can you edit your fiddle to have the same text as those from the image? So that we can properly see where to put where

Comment: @Swellar https://jsfiddle.net/19qwxkhf/13/

Comment: Explain problem clearly , what u have explained, what u want, what u had shown in screenshot, what is in fiddle everything mismatches

Comment: Where would the bold texts go? I can't see `test1` nor `hello` in the image

Comment: those labels are on the left side

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/


/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

section {
  width: 300px;
}

.column {
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
  display: inline-block;
}

.badge-success {
  background: green !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  min-width: 0px !important;
  /* If you need */
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.badge-important {
  background: red !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

#tab-reporting {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    &.inactive {
      margin-top: 25px;
      opacity: 0.3;
    }
  }
  label {
    width: 245px;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
  li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: table;
    &.survey-start {
      margin-top: 15px;
    }
    > label {
      font-weight: normal;
      margin-left: 30px;
      padding-top: 7px;
      &.colspan {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
    .colspan-nest {
      text-indent: 25px;
    }
    > span {
      display: table-cell;
      min-width: 175px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 0;
      background: #ddd;
      padding: 7px;
      &.no-background {
        background: none;
      }
    }
  }
  .txt {
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  .lh {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    padding: 12px 0 5px;
  }
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<article class="tab-pane" id="tab-reporting">
  <section>
    <div class="column">
      <span style="display:block;text-align:center;">Referrals sent</span>
      <ul class="active">
        <li>
          <span class="badge badge-success">View details</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          View details
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <span style="display:block;text-align:center;">Patient response</span>
      <ul class="active">
        <li>
          <span class="badge badge-important">View details</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="badge badge-success">View details</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</article>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this part of code :-
`<span class="badge badge-success"  style="display:block;">Test1</span>
<center>This text should be above Hello badge and centered</center>`

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}


.badge-success {
  background: green !important;
  color: #fff !important;

  min-width: 0px !important;

  /* If you need */
  padding: 0px !important;

}

.badge-important {
  background: red !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

#tab-reporting {
  padding-bottom: 100px;

  ul {
    list-style-type: none;

    &.inactive {
      margin-top: 25px;
      opacity: 0.3;
    }
  }

  label {
    width: 245px;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }

  li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: table;

    &.survey-start {
      margin-top: 15px;
    }

    > label {
      font-weight: normal;
      margin-left: 30px;
      padding-top: 7px;

      &.colspan {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }

    .colspan-nest {
      text-indent: 25px;
    }

    > span {
      display: table-cell;
      min-width: 175px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 0;
      background: #ddd;
      padding: 7px;

      &.no-background {
        background: none;
      }
    }
  }

  .txt {
    padding-left: 5px;
  }

  .lh {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    padding: 12px 0 5px;
  }
}
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
span {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<article class="tab-pane" id="tab-reporting">
  <section>
      <ul class="active">
        <li>
          <label>Test 1</label>
          <span class="badge badge-success"  style="display:block;">Test1</span>
          <center>This text should be above Hello badge and centered</center>
          <span class="badge badge-important">Hello</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>Test 2</label>
          <span class="badge badge-success" style="display:block;">Test1</span>
          <center>This text should be above Hello 2 badge and centered</center>
          <span class="badge badge-important">Hello 2</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </section>
</article>
```